# React best practice for changing state of parent component from child without rerendering all children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks, usecallback

I have a project where I'm displaying cards that contain attributes of a person in a textfield, and the user can edit the textfield to directly change that person's attribute values. However every time they're editing the textfield it causes a rerender of all cards which slows down the app. Here is an example:

```
export default Parent() {  
    const [personList, setPersonList] = useState(/* list of person objects*/);
    const modifyPerson(index, property, value) {
          const newPersonList = _.cloneDeep(personList);
          newPersonList[index][property] = value;
          setPersonList(newPersonList);
    }

    const children = personList.map((person, index) => {
           <Person
               modifyPerson={modifyPerson}
               index=index
               /*properties on the person */ 
           />
    });

    return <div> {children} </div>
}

export default Person(props) {
    
    const fields = /* assume a list of these textfields for each property */
           <TextField 
            value={props.name}
            onChange={(e) => modifyPerson(props.index,"name",e.target.value)}
            value={props.name} >
    return {fields};
}
```

So essentially when the child's text field is updated, it triggers a state change in the parent that stores the new value, then refreshes what the Child looks like. There's no button that the user clicks to "save" the values-- as soon as they edit the textfield it's a permanent change. And also the parent needs to know the new values of every Person because there's some functions that require knowledge of the current state of the person list. The Person component contains images that slow down the rendering if done inefficiently.

Is there a better way to make this design more performant and reduce rerenders? I attempted to use useCallback to preserve the functions but I don't it works in this specific design because the property and values are different-- do I have to create a new "modifyPerson" for each exact attribute?

Comment: If you provide a `key` value to the `<Person />` component React will manage selective rerenders of only those components that have changed. Be sure not to use `index` as a key as it will lead to headaches if you ever re-order your array, instead use a unique property of each mapped element. `<Person modifyPerson={modifyPerson} key={person.id} .../>`. see: [React: Lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

React.Memo will check the props passed to the component and only if the props changes , it will re-render that particular component.

So, if you have multiple `Person` component which are getting props which are explicit to those `Person`, and when you change a particular `Person` component which leads to Parent state getting updated, only that `Person` component which you had modified will re-render because its props will change(assuming that you pass the changed value to it).

The other components will have the same props and wont change.

```
export default React.memo(Person(props) {
    
    const fields = /* assume a list of these textfields for each property */
           <TextField 
            value={props.name}
            onChange={(e) => modifyPerson(props.index,"name",e.target.value)}
            value={props.name} >
    return {fields};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said `React.memo()` is the way to go here, but this will still re-render because you recreate `modifyPerson` every time. You can use `useCallback` to always get the same identity of the function, but with your current implementation you would have to add `personList` as dependency so that doesn't work either.

There is a trick with `setPersonList` that it also accepts a function that takes the current state and returns the next state. That way `modifyPerson` doesn't depend on any outer scope (expect for `setPersonList` which is guaranteed to always have the same identity by react) and needs to be created only once.

```js
const modifyPerson = useCallback((index, property, value) {
    setPersonList(currentPersonList => {
        const newPersonList = _.cloneDeep(currentPersonList);
        newPersonList[index][property] = value;
        return newPersonList;
    })
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! A follow up- suppose there could be different roles that each person belongs to that warrants creating a new component, e.g: creating a Teachers component that displays a list of Person components who are teachers, etc. Each of these components would accept a prop that is a subset of all People from the main PersonList.
Would it not be possible with this current approach because as soon as I modify a person of a certain role, that entire role component (and all the Person components inside) will rerender because the props are different (because the subset list is modified?)